# How to disable "Publish content to your Wall" when using Facebook's new Oauth2?

Tags: facebook, oauth

Right now when I use Facebook's new OAuth2 system, it tells the user that my app is requesting to "Publish content to your Wall".  How do I disable this (for fear of scaring off users), as I don't need this enabled.  Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the user to authorize one of the extended permissions for your app is kind of the point behind authenticating. You may want to see if the data you need is exposed without authenticating (if you in fact need data). If you can get the uid you can see what is exposed to everyone, and per the privacy changes, I mean everyone. Until the privacy "fire", there was quite a bit exposed to everyone, now 'everyone' means the least restrictive tier among multiple privacy tiers rather than the happy-go-lucky default.

So really the question is, what permission are you trying to get?

There are a few unknown variables here such as what type of app you are making etc.

Check your code for one of the [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), you are probably sending one of them such as offline_access in your auth call.